# canvasContext not working after pdfjs-dist update in ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

i have a Typ Problem with "canvasContext" after updating the pdfjs-dist, whice is a can't understand

this is the Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw6vD.png)

```
 const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(viewport.width, viewport.height, 'pdf');

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    await page.render({ canvasContext: context, viewport }).promise;

    page.cleanup();

    if (mimeType === 'image/jpeg') return canvas.toBuffer('image/jpeg', { quality: 80 });
    return canvas.toBuffer('image/png', { compressionLevel: 6 });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Error && 'name' in e && e.name == 'PasswordException') return new MissingPasswordError(e.message);
    throw e;
  }
```

i tried to solve the problem with "as" and put the typ,, it did't work